# Joining two MySQL tables by 1 single column in common

Tags: mysql, database, select, join

did quite a bit of looking online, still stumped.  Not sure how to join these two tables.

So here's the data (apologizes, still figuring this wonderful site out)

Table 1:people

1. peopleID
2. firstname
3. lastname

Table 2: locationMember

1. locationID
2. peopleID
3. notes

My goal:  Join these tables at the userID and select and output all the data returned.  I want to SELECT every row in Table 2 that has a specific LocationID, and pull the name of the users from the Table 1.

Most recent attempt that failed:

```
SELECT m.peopleID, m.notes, p.nameFirst, p.nameLast
FROM locationMember AS m, people AS p 
JOIN locationMember ON m.peopleID = p.peopleID
WHERE m.locationID='".ID."'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your `JOIN` is a bit off. You need to declare the table **after** the `JOIN`. You also don't need `AS` in the aliasing

```
SELECT m.peopleID, m.notes, p.nameFirst, p.nameLast
FROM locationMember m 
    INNER JOIN people p ON m.peopleID = p.peopleID
WHERE m.locationID='".ID."'
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, hope this helps others

```
SELECT
locationMember.peopleID,
locationMember.notes,
people.nameFirst,
people.nameLast
FROM locationMember
INNER JOIN people ON locationMember.peopleID=people.peopleID
WHERE locationMember.locationID='id here'
```